# VBA - Set Excel formula containing quotation marks as cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get my VB script to enter an Excel formula into a cell. Unfortunately I had no luck so far.

```
    Sheets("ABC").Select
Range("B2").Value = "=IF(Mat_Location!F2=0;"";Mat_Location!F2)"
```

After some googling and searching on this site I figured it would be because of the quotation marks and so I tried changing the quotation marks to double quotation marks.

```
    Sheets("ABC").Select
Range("B2").Value = "=IF(Mat_Location!F2=0;"""";Mat_Location!F2)"
```

That also didn't help.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To add quotation mark use four of them ie, myString = "Adam said, " & """" & "Hello Jane!" & """"

Comment: The formula is fine (Assuming ";" is your delimeter as opposed to ","). A few basic checks, is ABC protected and B2 a locked cell? does the sheet "Mat_Location" exist in the workbook that is active in that point of the code (Sheets is not qualified explicitly to a specific workbook in this case)

Comment: @JohnMuggins he's specifically said he tried that.

Comment: Yes, now I see that.  Thanks for letting me know @Zerk  I wasn't even aware it was for a formula.  The tags say vba and excel and that is my only expertise.  I try to stay away from formulas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your multiple `"` with `Chr(34)`, it's easier to debug it this way.

Also, there's no need to `Select` the sheet first.

```
Sheets("ABC").Range("B2").FormulaLocal = "=IF(Mat_Location!F2=0;" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ";Mat_Location!F2)"
```

**Note**: it seems your Excel's regional settings is having `;` as a delimeter inside the formula. The default settings is `,` , so for my Excel setting (maybe also yours) it might be:

```
Sheets("ABC").Range("B2").Formula = "=IF(Mat_Location!F2=0," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ",Mat_Location!F2)"
```

Comment: @AxelRichter thanks for fixing , in the middle of "debug" here :)